# Extract binary from a list within a list in Erlang

Tags: erlang

i have a binary string in a list within a list in erlang, any ideas on how to extract just the binary string

eg.

```
    Whatihave = [[<<"hello">>]].

    Whatiwant = <<"hello">>.
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to do that:

1. Use pattern matching:

   ```
   [[Whatiwant]] = Whatihave.
   ```
2. Call the `hd` function, which gets the first element of a list, twice:

   ```
   Whatiwant = hd(hd(Whatihave)).
   ```
3. Call `iolist_to_binary`, which is a more general function that can convert "iolists" (deep lists of strings and binaries) to binaries:

   ```
   Whatiwant = iolist_to_binary(Whatihave).
   ```

Comment: thanks, that pattern matching was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern matching

`[[Whatiwant]] = [[<<"hello">>]].`

The variable Whatiwant contains the binary string.